# Como enviar um único e-mail para todos os administradores, no laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou precisando implementar o envio de e-mails para um determinado grupo de usuários, tipo administradores, editores, revisores.

Seria necessário usar uma fila para isso ou algo parecido?

Enfim, quero selecionar um determinado grupo de usuários e enviar um e-mail para todos os e-mails deste grupo. Isso é possível?

Estou usando a versão 5.4 do laravel.

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar a opção `bcc` (enviar email com cópia oculta)?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.4

Segunda a documentação

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail

O método *to()* , aceita um endereço de email, uma instância do *user*, ou uma colecção de *user* também pode passar uma colecção de objectos que *Mailer* vai extrair automaticamente a propriedade name e email para definir os recipientes.

O uso de *queues* é recomenda para diminuir o tempo de reposta.

Não aconselho a colocar vários endereços num só email alguns provedores rejeitam mensagens com demasiados endereços.

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($coleccao_de_users)
    ->bcc($coleccao_de_objectos)
    ->send(new Anuncio($anuncio));
```

Comment: Será necessário um foreach para extrair cada e-mail e nome e assim enviar o e-mail para casa usuário?

Comment: Penso que depende do número de usuários, 5, 10, 15, 1000 ...

Comment: No caso um dos grupos têm 20 usuários. Preciso mesmo usar um foreach? Ou o bcc resolve?